# How do you know if a started query is executing or not?

Tags: marketing-cloud

SFMC/Email/Interactions/Query - click "Start"-arrow

Does the system have a way to monitor progress or success/failure of the query?

Apart from moving in and out of your result Data Extension and hoping for a record count > 0 ?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this without some kind of API integration is to add the Query to an Automation using Automation Studio. When the automation has completed running you know the query is also complete. You can also use a Program if you don't have access to Automation Studio.

However, a better solution is to use the SOAP API to execute the query, and check its status over time to determine if it is complete or not. This will also tell you if the query has erred.

Answer (score 2):

Put the Query in a workflow within Automation Studio and run it manually there (create as Scheduled, then Run Once).
Additionally cool: If the Query fails, Automation Studio will tell you the reason why (e. g. when UNION two Data Extensions: Primary Key used more than one time).